# JAVA: Convert a Enum Set to a String Seperated by List & Quotes

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

Hello I currently have an enum Set and would like to convert this enum Set to a String.

So Convert

`Set <AlertSide> mySet  = Sets.newHashSet(AlertSide.THREAT,AlertSide.TARGET);`

To

`'THREAT','TARGET'`

What would be the best way to do this?  I'm not too familair with streams but I believe the correct line of thinking is something along the lines of

`mySet.stream().map(Enum::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))`

However this only provides me `'THREAT,ALERT'`

Perhaps there is a way using Strings.join?

Comment: A `Set` of enum is not an `EnumSet` and a `HashSet` does not guaranty a particular oder.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have a `Set` of enums, you should use [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) *(available since Java 5)*:

```
Set<AlertSide> mySet = EnumSet.of(AlertSide.THREAT, AlertSide.TARGET);
```

If you want a string with content `'THREAT','TARGET'`, then you need to add the single-quotes yourself:

```
mySet.stream().map(e -> "'" + e + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

*Result*

```
'THREAT','TARGET'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `String.join()` for this. For example:

```
Set<AlertSide> mySet = EnumSet.of(AlertSide.THREAT, AlertSide.TARGET);
String result = String.join(",", mySet.stream()
  .map(it -> "'" + it + "'")
  .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Or... you can also use Collectors.joining(), like:

```
String result = mySet.stream()
  .map(it -> "'" + it + "'")
  .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

`result` -> `'THREAT','TARGET'`

Comment: Question starts *"I currently have an enum Set"*. Changing the pre-conditions makes this answer non-applicable to the question, i.e. not that useful. --- Answer says *"you can use String.join()"*, then proceeds to show example code that doesn't use `String.join()`. Not a useful example for that, then.

Comment: omg, thanks for pointing this out Andreas. I had originally use String.join() but then followed the IDE's suggestion to optimize it. I've updated my answer to show both.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `joining(CharSequence delimiter,CharSequence prefix,CharSequence suffix)`

```
String result = mySet.stream()
            .map(AlertSide::name)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
```

Comment: The disadvantage of `joining("','", "'", "'")` is that it will produce a `''` for an empty set.

Comment: @Holger I think it happens rarely since we should have an enum without any constant.

Comment: A set doesn't always contain all constants of an enum. There's no reason to assume that an empty set implies that the enum type has no constants.

Comment: @Holger, RIGHT!